# How do I write Sqrt[x] as x^(1/2)

Tags: simplifying-expressions, output-formatting

Sometimes it is needed to keep the powers as the fractional form. However Mathematica tends to write `x^(1/2)` as `Sqrt[x]`.

**How do I keep x^(1/2) as it is in the output without writing it as Sqrt[x]?**

Here is a simple example:

```
 expr = Rationalize[1+x^(0.5),0.0000001] >> output.m
```

Output is

```
 1 + Sqrt[x]
```

Instead I want the output to have the form

```
 1 + x^(1/2)
```

I could not find any solution for this.

Comment: `1 + x^(1/2) /. Sqrt[z_] :> z^HoldForm[1/2]` is close. You would need to `ReleaseHold` to do much with it.

Comment: It occured to me as well. But since this is at the output level (i.e. this expression is going to be saved in an output file), I can not use `ReleaseHold` before.   For me then easiest way is to manipulate the expression in the output file by other means. But I hope there must be some better ways to do it in Mathematica itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`Put`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Put) (the [`FullForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FullForm) for `>>`) uses [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) to write expressions to the file. So, one idea is to modify the [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm) rules temporarily:

```
Unprotect[Power];
Format[Power[x_, 1/2], InputForm] /; $Sqrt := Power[x, SequenceForm[1]/2]
Protect[Power];
```

[`SequenceForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceForm) is a special wrapper that is not visible inside [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm). By including the wrapper [`SequenceForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceForm) around the `1`, the [`Sqrt`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sqrt) rewriting rule doesn't fire. Wrapping [`SequenceForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SequenceForm) around the `1/2` won't work because then no parentheses will be used to wrap the exponent.

Then, blocking `$Sqrt` to [`True`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/True) will cause the new format to be used:

```
Block[{$Sqrt = True}, Put[1 + Sqrt[x], "tmp.m"]]
```

Check:

```
Import["tmp.m","String"]
```

> "1 + x^(1/2)"

Comment: Thanks. What about other export methods like `WriteString` ? Currently I am trying to export a list `{1,2,x^(1/2)}` as `Text`/`String` like `WriteString["tmp.m",ExportString[{1,2,x^(1/2)},"Text"] ]`.
I have to adopt similar methods?
 Basically it seems that there is no straightforward way to implement it globally within Mathematica.
What is it so special about `Sqrt`, other powers are written as it is except for `1/2` which is always translated to `Sqrt`. :-/

Comment: @Boogeyman The same method works for `Export` to "Text".

Answer (score 3):

```
g=x^(1/2)/. Rational[1,2]->Defer[1/2];
expr = Rationalize[1 + g, 0.0000001] >> output.m

<<output.m
```

[image]

```
WriteString["tmp.m", ExportString[{1,2,g},"Text"]]

<<tmp.m
```

[image]

As mentioned in the comments, the files created above contain `x^Defer[1/2]`. If the goal is to get a text file with `x^(1/2)`, then it can be created from the original output file:

```
WriteString["outputNew.m", 
 StringReplace[Import["output.m", "Text"], "Defer[1/2]" -> "(1/2)"]]
```

Comment: In output.m, I get `1 + x^Defer[1/2]`, not `1 + x ^(1/2)`.  What do you get?

Comment: Correct. The file still carries the Defer.